# Simplest way to count words in a file

Tags: scala

I'm trying to code in the simplest way a program to count word occurrences in file in Scala Language. So far I have these piece of code:

```
import scala.io.Codec.string2codec
import scala.io.Source
import scala.reflect.io.File

object WordCounter {
    val SrcDestination: String = ".." + File.separator + "file.txt"
    val Word = "\\b([A-Za-z\\-])+\\b".r

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val counter = Source.fromFile(SrcDestination)("UTF-8")
                .getLines
                .map(l => Word.findAllIn(l.toLowerCase()).toSeq)
                .toStream
                .groupBy(identity)
                .mapValues(_.length)

        println(counter)
    }
}
```

Don't bother of regexp expression. I would like to know how to extract single words from
sequence retrieved in this line:

```
map(l => Word.findAllIn(l.toLowerCase()).toSeq)
```

in order to get each word occurency counted. Currently I'm getting map with counted words sequences.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can turn the file lines into words by splitting them with the regex `"\\W+"` (`flatmap` is lazy so it doesn't need to load the entire file into memory).  To count occurrences you can fold over a `Map[String, Int]` updating it with each word (much more memory and time efficient than using `groupBy`)

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")
  .getLines
  .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){
     (count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
  }
```

Comment: I'm really new to scala, so I have a bit of trouble understanding the anonymous function you pass to foldLeft. How does it know to reverse the order of the tuple you pass in to (count, word)?

Comment: The count is actually a Map[String, Int] and the word is a String.

Comment: Yes I understand now, the first element of the tuple is the accumulator, and the second element is the element foldLeft is iterating over.

Comment: It took me a long time to understand this. I used the understanding to answer another question on SO and explained what is happening in more detail.. Perhaps it will help someone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006847/finding-out-duplicates-in-a-dataset-in-scala/41008312#41008312

Comment: The foldLeft function, has an empty Map[String, Int], as I understand for every new word it finds, it creates a new map(since it is immutable!), does it have performance issues ?

Comment: Using mutable.Map should result in a much better performance.

Comment: (count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1)) this line could be have been better understood if was written as (accumulator, word) => accumulator + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1)). That means here count (name is misleading)  is basically the Map what is getting used as the accumulator.

Answer (score 15):

I think the following is slightly easier to understand:

```
Source.fromFile("file.txt").
  getLines().
  flatMap(_.split("\\W+")).
  toList.
  groupBy((word: String) => word).
  mapValues(_.length)
```

Comment: FWIW, I think you could replace `(word: String) => word` with `identity`.

Comment: This would hold the whole file content in memory, while the accepted answers would not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think I see the problem. Try using `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
flatMap(l => Word.findAllIn(l.toLowerCase()).toSeq)
```

This will concatenate all of your sequences together so that `groupBy` is done on individual words instead of at the line level.

---

**A note about your Regex**

I know you said not to worry about your Regex, but here are a couple changes you can make to make it a little more readable. Here's what you have right now:

```
val Word = "\\b([A-Za-z\\-])+\\b".r
```

First, you can use Scala's triple-quoted strings so you don't have to escape your backslashes:

```
val Word = """\b([A-Za-z\-])+\b""".r
```

Second, if you put the `-` at the *beginning* of your character class then you don't need to escape it:

```
val Word = """\b([-A-Za-z])+\b""".r
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, in addition to retrieving words with `Source`, we can use the [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a reduce step:

```
import scala.io.Source

Source.fromFile("file.txt")
  .getLines.to(LazyList)
  .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
  .groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
```

The `groupMapReduce` stage, similarly to Hadoop's map/reduce logic,

- `group`s words by themselves (identity) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped word occurrence to 1 (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within a group of words (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) of what can be translated by:

```
seq.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.map(_ => 1).reduce(_ + _))
```

Also note the cast from `Iterator` to `LazyList` in order to use a collection which provides `groupMapReduce` (we don't use a `Stream`, since starting `Scala 2.13`, `LazyList` is the recommended replacement of `Stream`s).

---

On the same principle, one could also use a `for-comprehension` version:

```
(for {
  line <- Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.to(LazyList)
  word <- line.split("\\W+")
} yield word)
.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. This will chop a file.
Hashmap is a good bet for high performance and will outperform any sort of sort.
There is a more terse sort and slice function in there too you can look at.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException

/**.
 * Cohesive static method object for file handling.
 */
object WordCountFileHandler {

  val FILE_FORMAT = "utf-8"

  /**
   * Take input from file. Split on spaces.
   * @param fileLocationAndName string location of file
   * @return option of string iterator
   */
  def apply (fileLocationAndName: String) : Option[Iterator[String]] = {
    apply (fileLocationAndName, " ")
  }

  /**
   * Split on separator parameter.
   * Speculative generality :P
   * @param fileLocationAndName string location of file
   * @param wordSeperator split on this string
   * @return
   */
  def apply (fileLocationAndName: String, wordSeperator: String): Option[Iterator[String]] = {
    try{
      val words = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileLocationAndName).getLines() //scala io.Source is a bit hackey. No need to close file.

      //Get rid of anything funky... need the double space removal for files like the README.md...
      val wordList = words.reduceLeft(_ + wordSeperator + _).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", "").replaceAll("  ", "").split(wordSeperator)
      //wordList.foreach(println(_))
      wordList.length match {
        case 0 => return None
        case _ => return Some(wordList.toIterator)
      }
    } catch {
      case _:FileNotFoundException => println("file not found: " + fileLocationAndName); return None
      case e:Exception => println("Unknown exception occurred during file handling: \n\n" + e.getStackTrace); return None
    }
  }
}

import collection.mutable

/**
 * Static method object.
 * Takes a processed map and spits out the needed info
 * While a small performance hit is made in not doing this during the word list analysis,
 * this does demonstrate cohesion and open/closed much better.
 * author: jason goodwin
 */
object WordMapAnalyzer {

  /**
   * get input size
   * @param input
   * @return
   */
  def getNumberOfWords(input: mutable.Map[String, Int]): Int = {
    input.size
  }

  /**
   * Should be fairly logarithmic given merge sort performance is generally about O(6nlog2n + 6n).
   * See below for more performant method.
   * @param input
   * @return
   */

  def getTopCWordsDeclarative(input: mutable.HashMap[String, Int], c: Int): Map[String, Int] = {
    val sortedInput = input.toList.sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
    sortedInput.take(c).toMap
  }

  /**
   * Imperative style is used here for much better performance relative to the above.
   * Growth can be reasoned at linear growth on random input.
   * Probably upper bounded around O(3n + nc) in worst case (ie a sorted input from small to high).
   * @param input
   * @param c
   * @return
   */
  def getTopCWordsImperative(input: mutable.Map[String, Int], c: Int): mutable.Map[String, Int] = {
    var bottomElement: (String, Int) = ("", 0)
    val topList = mutable.HashMap[String, Int]()

    for (x <- input) {
      if (x._2 >= bottomElement._2 && topList.size == c ){
        topList -= (bottomElement._1)
        topList +=((x._1, x._2))
        bottomElement = topList.toList.minBy(_._2)
      } else if (topList.size < c ){
        topList +=((x._1, x._2))
        bottomElement = topList.toList.minBy(_._2)
      }
    }
    //println("Size: " + topList.size)

    topList.asInstanceOf[mutable.Map[String, Int]]
  }
}

object WordMapCountCalculator {

  /**
   * Take a list and return a map keyed by words with a count as the value.
   * @param wordList List[String] to be analysed
   * @return HashMap[String, Int] with word as key and count as pair.
   * */

   def apply (wordList: Iterator[String]): mutable.Map[String, Int] = {
    wordList.foldLeft(new mutable.HashMap[String, Int])((word, count) => {
      word get(count) match{
        case Some(x) => word += (count -> (x+1))   //if in map already, increment count
        case None => word += (count -> 1)          //otherwise, set to 1
      }
    }).asInstanceOf[mutable.Map[String, Int]] 
}
```