# Scala match certain words and count frequency

Tags: scala

I read this post: [Scala beginners - simplest way to count words in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487413/scala-beginners-simplest-way-to-count-words-in-file)

The code is just one line and it's really magnificent. However, there is no way for me to understand what it is:

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")
  .getLines
  .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){
     (count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
  }
```

I stop being able to understand at the `foldLeft` part, which directly imparis me ability to modify this code. `foldLeft` is defined as this: `def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B`

What does this `foldLeft` do? How come it can extract out and put in `count` and `word` and put into the partial function of the second curry function?

The words I want to match are represented in a `Map`:

```
  val dictionary = Map(
    """will""" -> 1,
    """going to""" -> 2,
    """future""" -> 3
  )
```

How can I incorporate this `Map` with that code? Or should I try something else entirely?

I came up with this bad idea: I can probably throw a for loop outside..but it'll look very ugly.

Comment: Nice blog on foldLeft and foldRight to get you started: http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/10/scala-code-review-foldleft-and-foldright/

Comment: @I.K. Yeah I copied the `foldLeft` definition from that blog :) And I read it before...although I guess I need to take more time to fully understand this

Comment: So all the foldLeft is doing is taking the list of words per line, and putting it in the Map with that word and it's count so far.

Comment: @I.K. The map is `Map[String, Int]`, while the curry function is `(count, word)`. Isn't the order backwards?

Comment: Looking at the answers so far, it seems to me that you might want to clarify whether your question is about understanding `foldLeft` or about how to make some modification to the logic, and if the latter, you should clarify exactly what new behavior you'd like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you want to count only words that are present as keys in `dictionary`, you'd add a filter:

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")
  .getLines
  .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
  .filter(dictionary.contains(_))
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){
     (count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
  }
```

Now, for a general explanation of how `foldLeft` is used here...

Plugging our types into the `foldLeft` definition, we have:
`foldLeft[Map[String, Int]](z: Map[String, Int])(f: (Map[String, Int], String) => Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int]`

So simplified, `foldLeft` takes two curried parameters, an initial value for the accumulator (an empty `Map`, in our case), and a function that itself takes two parameters: the accumulator, and the current item in the structure being traversed (the current word).

So, for each call to the function, `count` will be the current `Map` of counts and `word` will be the current word.

For each word we will return a new `Map` with the count for the current word (0 if it doesn't exist) incremented by 1.  The final result of `foldLeft` is the complete `Map` of counts.

Comment: I only wish to extract words that are present in the `dictionary`

Comment: So do you actually care about counts?  I'm having trouble figuring out how the example code snippet actually relates to what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I do care about counts!

Answer (score 2):

Let `file.txt` contain for instance

> He will be going to the future, for the future is going to be the present.

Thus

```
val file = scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").mkString
```

uploads the file contents onto a string (max string size is a limiting factor in this approach; StringBuffer may be considered otherwise).

Then for a given dictionary, namely for instance

```
val dictionary = Map( """will""" -> 1,
                      """going to""" -> 2,
                      """future""" -> 3 )
```

we have that

```
dictionary.map { case(k,v) => k -> k.r.findAllIn(file).size }
res: Map[String,Int] = Map( will -> 1, going to -> 2, future -> 2 )
```

To wrap up this code, consider

```
implicit class RichWordCount(val filename: String) extends AnyVal {
  def dictioCount(dictionary: Map[String,Int]): Map[String,Int] = {
    val file = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename).mkString
    dictionary.map { case(k,v) => k -> k.r.findAllIn(file).size }
  }
}
```

Then we can invoke it with

```
"file.txt".dictioCount(dictionary)
res: Map[String,Int] = Map(will -> 1, going to -> 2, future -> 2)
```

Comment: You sound almost exactly like my professor in Theory of Computation, he is a mathematician btw.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question (I'm not sure that I correctly understant your question), but I think this code to count word occurrences is simpler:

```
  val words = List("the", "the", "water")
  val groupedWords = words.groupBy(word => word)
  println(groupedWords)
  val wordsWithCount = groupedWords.mapValues(_.size)
  println(wordsWithCount)
```

`groupBy` just classify the data into subsets according to some key.  In this case, I just take the key to be the word itself (see the output below).   By the way, `groupBy` is basically an implementation of `foldLeft` for the purpose of grouping things.

The output is:

```
Map(water -> List(water), the -> List(the, the))
Map(water -> 1, the -> 2)
```

**EDIT:**

I think I now understand that you don't want to count all words, but only certain words:

```
val validWords = dictionary.keys.toSet
val filteredWords = words.filter(word => validWords.contains(word))
```

(For performance, it might be better to first carry out the grouping, and only filter the valid words at the very end.  But that would depend on the dictionary size, the number of words to process and how often the words are repeated.)

Comment: Does `words` here refer to a document? I'm reading a text file line by line.

Comment: I like to give runnable examples.  In your case `words = scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))`.

Comment: What is the collection type of this `words`??

Comment: And I'm really sorry for asking this extra question what if instead of `validWords`, I want to eliminate a group of words maybe in a collection called `stopWords`?

Comment: `words` will be an `Iterator[String]` since `getLines` returns an `Iterator`.

Comment: You can put your stop words in any collection which has the `contains` method, or something equivalent.

Comment: so just write  `words.filter(word => !stopWords.contains(word))` ?

Comment: Yes. Or `filterNot(word => stopWords.contains(word))`.

Comment: Ehhhh this is better than my first version of my program: at least this is capturing something. However, it will miss the counts. For example, when I open my textpad and `search` the word "will", I get 175 counts, but when I use this program, I get 141 counts.

Comment: I'm sure this code works.  Likely it is another problem such as case-sensitivity.  You can try `validWords.contains(word.toLowerCase)`, where valid words are all lower case.  You would also have to change `words.groupBy(word => word.toLowerCase)`.

Comment: Reading the answer from @user3189923 I realized I was assuming that the keys in the dictionary are String's, but they are really regexs.

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of strings, the function gets the frequency of each string and returns an array of tuples.

```
def countWordOccourence(words: Array[String]): Array[(String, Int)] = {
        val sortedArray  = words.sorted
        var tupleArray: Array[(String, Int)] = Array()
        var currentCount: Int = 1
        for (i: Int <- 0 to (sortedArray.length - 1)) {
          if (i + 1 < sortedArray.length) { // prevent out of bound access
            if (sortedArray(i) == sortedArray(i+1)) { // same words should be next to each other
              currentCount += 1
            } else{
              // End of sorted elements , put elements in a tuple
              tupleArray = tupleArray ++ Array((sortedArray(i), currentCount))
              currentCount = 1 // reset the counter
            }
          }else {
            // Just in case there is a last element
            if (sortedArray(i) != sortedArray(i -1)) {
              tupleArray = tupleArray ++ Array((sortedArray(i), 1))
            }
          }

        }
        return  tupleArray
      }
```