# Finding out duplicates in a dataset in scala

Tags: scala, duplicates

I have a dataset which is a DataSet of String and it has the data

```
12348,5,233,234559,4
12348,5,233,234559,4
12349,6,233,234560,5
12350,7,233,234561,6
```

I want to figure out the duplicate rows in a dataset, how do i do that?    I would like to remove the duplicates. in the example, the duplicated row is `12348,5,233,234559,4` and I want to output just a single instance of it

How do i go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimas answer should work. Here is another solution.

I **think (not positive)** `groupby` would hold all of the data in memory.. so perhaps this would be better for you.

```
val rows = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.txt") // Assuming data is in a file
             .getLines  // Create an iterator from lines in file
             .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){ // Fold over empty Map
                (acc, row) => acc + (row -> (acc.getOrElse(row, 0) + 1))}  // Keep accumulator to track of row counts as fold is done
             .filter(t => t._2 > 1)  // Filter to tuples with more than one row
```

I'm new to scala myself, I actually spent a while answering this as practice haha. Confusing, but it makes sense!

Think of a Map like a dictionary. You can store pairs in it. In scala, you can add/update a key/value pair by adding a pair to it.
`Map(b -> 4) + ("c" -> 2)` would return `Map(b -> 4, c -> 2)`. Expanding on that, `Map(b -> 4, c -> 2) + ("b" -> 1)` returns `Map(b -> 1, c -> 2)`. What acc is (renamed from count for clarity) is the accumulator of a growing object as the iterator is folded. Each time it hits a new row, it is checking to see if that row has is in the Map yet (again, think dictionary). If the value is there, it takes the previous value with `getOrElse` and adds 1 to it, then updates the acc Map with that new pair, or it initializes it at one if it doesn't exist yet (since it was the first time the row was seen).

Here is the best blog I found for learning folding. The author describes it succinctly and accurately: https://coderwall.com/p/4l73-a/scala-fold-foldleft-and-foldright

Comment: Thanks this worked. Much appreciated. Can you please explain - (count, row) => count + (row -> (count.getOrElse(row, 0) + 1)) .. i am new to scala.

Comment: You think, `Map` won't hold data in memory? :D

Comment: Hey @user3897533 , added in an explanation above. Scala can be tricky! Dima, I understand this will use memory. How much of it is what I was unsure of. Get lines returns an iterator, and folding simply iterates over that iterator, so I didn't think the entire file is ever actually stored in order to do this operation. Is that incorrect? I also stated I wasn't positive and was merely offering another solution..

Comment: Thanks for this writeup, having done a lot of work in Java and Swift and Kotlin more recently, this is still pretty unsatisfying. There has to be a better way??

Answer (score 1):

`dataSet.groupBy(identity).collect { case (k,v) if v.size > 1 => k }`

Answer (score -1):

If you use scala collections (Like `Seq`, `List`) you have a method called `.distinct`. Otherwise you can transform it in a `Set` which removes duplicates by default (but doesn't conserve the order)