# Count the patterns in text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a huge text file. I want a count of words that appear after the phrase "i feel" from that text file.

Here is a small example of what the file is like:

```
i feel awesome
i feel nothing but i also feel awesome
i feel good.
```

I read the text file and match lines that contain **"i feel"**. Now my output is in the form of:

```
res3: Array[String] = Array("awesome", "nothing", "good", ....)
```

I need to find the occurrence of these words in the text file.

Code that I am using so far for this purpose is as follows:

```
 val c1 = scala.io.Source.fromFile("text.txt", "UTF-8").
   getLines.flatMap(regexpr.findAllIn(_).toList).
   foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) {
     (count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
   }
```

But this gives me a count of only a few words that are present in that array. 
For example, it returns:

```
c1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(awesome -> 1, nothing -> 4)
```

It doesn't return the count of *all* the words present in the list. Additionally, how can I write the `Map[String,Int]` to a text file??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala beginners - simplest way to count words in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487413/scala-beginners-simplest-way-to-count-words-in-file)

Comment: The solution that you are referring to doesn't return all occurrences. i have updated the code in original comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of lines in a text file:

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("text.txt","UTF-8").getLines
```

Here is a Java print writer:

```
val f = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.File("counts.txt"))
```

Here is grouping the matches for the words after "i feel" statements written to a text file:

```
lines.flatMap {
  "i feel (\\w+)".r.findAllMatchIn(_).map(_.group(1)) // Return only paren matches
}.toTraversable.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).foreach {
  case (word, count) => f.write(s"$count\t$word\n") // Separate by tab
}
```

And then closing the file

```
f.close()
```

See the [Scala documentation on regular expressions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html)

Comment: kindly check my updated question. You are missing the point . i need to find the strings present in that particular array in a big text file.

Comment: Thankyou so much:)